# How to Make and automatic timer reset in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, timer, delphi-7

Could someone tell me how to make a timer Reset after a given time ? Like i'm trying to make a clock , and i would like it to reset , and start over (like after 60 min , and start over from 0).

Comment: Reset and start again is exactly what timers already do. I don't understand the question. And as for clocks, you don't want to use a timer to keep track of time.

Answer (score 0):

Have your `OnTimer` event update the timer's `Tag` property, or a separate variable, with how much time has elapsed, and then reset the timer when that value reaches your threshold.

Or you could simply run a separate timer that triggers one time after your desired interval elapses, and then reset both timers together.